# How can I prevent solar flares?

Tags: terraforming, stars

Quite simply, people are trying to terraform extrasolar planets, starting with Proxima Centauri B. Assuming it is not tidally locked, is it possible to protect the planet from solar flares or to alter the sun to prevent it from flaring?

Comment: Are solar flares dangerous?

Comment: Is it possible to stop the formation of a solar flare? Not in any way that humans know about. Humanity suffers from solar flares (in somewhat non-dramatic ways, like power surges) annually. No, we don't have a clue how to stop them or how to directly protect ourselves from them (that's what Van Allen Radiation Belts are for). All we can do is protect ourselves from the consequences of them (surge protectors).

Comment: BTW, unless you (for some reason) seriously want a Real Life solution to an entirely fictional problem (you should set your expectations for that...), what you may be looking for is literarily called a *[MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin).* A *MacGuffin* is the object or idea that serves as a focus for a story element, but is not itself important to the story. The traditional example is the Maltese Falcon in the movie, *The Maltese Falcon.* The statue itself is unimportant, but the role it plays in the story, is. Consider solving your problem using the same idea. (\*Cont.\*)

Comment: An example of a MacGuffin in a modern Sci-Fi story is the "Cold Fusion Device" placed by Spock in *Star Trek Beyond* to render an active volcano inert. How it worked is irrelevant. In fact, no details at all are provided because it's purpose as a volcano-nullifying-device isn't important to the story. I propose that your prevent-solar-flares technology be the same thing because, frankly, the more details you try to provide the less believable it will become. Unless you have an absolutely critical story element that depends on those details (you shouldn't), call it a MacGuffin and move on.

Comment: If you really want to prevent solar flares there's a bunch of ways to do it. You don't need macguffins. It's just absurdly expensive to stop solar flares at the sun, many orders of magnitude more expensive than just blocking the flares. But you could do it with advanced enough technology.

Answer (score 1):

Solar flares, and the mechanisms behind them, are orders of magnitude more energetic than anything terraforming-related. You're suggesting rearranging and manipulating the magnetics of an *entire star*.

If a few measly solar flares can knock your terraforming project to its knees, then you're doing it wrong. We're talking many trillions and trillions of kilograms of gravitationally-bound stuff. It's not going to blow away overnight. Any substantial alteration to an entire planet's atmosphere is going to endure many, many thousands of years on its own, without protection. Possibly millions.

With protection, and by topping off what meager tonnage leaves the planet due to solar activity, the atmosphere is going to endure indefinitely. If you have the ability to raise the atmospheric density enormously, and in timespans of mere centuries, then you *definitely* have the ability to do the light maintenance/topping-off to keep your new world in shape.

Comment: Nice frame challenge. +1.

Answer (score 0):

## Altering a star requires very powerful technology and is much more expensive than mitigation

Stars are enormously big. Solar flares themselves are typically ten times bigger than Proxima Centauri B. If you have the technology to manipulate the star on that scale, you can just build a giant space wall to block the solar flare for a fraction of the cost.

But lets say that your government is fine with the cost and has the spare power.

## Dyson swarm the star.

Build massive satellites orbiting the star, extracting its power. You'll probably need to break apart the planets Proxima Centauri d and Proxima Centauri c for this. Use the massive amounts of power to power computers and use powerful electromagnets and lasers to suppress any solar flares. Solar flares are just massive plasma and magnetic eruptions. Powerful enough computers and more power than the solar flares should be enough to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

You can take example from the Earth. A lot of solar flares actually don't hit us because they go in a different direction. The flare must be well targeted (by chance, of course).

With some handwaving you could try and help chance, trigger the flares and blow them away far from the planet.

A swarm of satellites  monitor the star standing as close as they can and in the meanwhile they recharge their batteries. When there is a storm on the surface thousands of them shoot their laser altogether hitting the same spot and summing their power. Thus they trigger a flare before the storm reaches the right alignment to hit the planet.

Answer (score 0):

**Early: Faraday Cage**

[image]

You have just unloaded your colony from orbit onto the bare rock of the planet. There is no atmosphere, and the colony is airtight. The life support systems  protect  the delicate humans from perishing. They do everything Earth's atmosphere does.  They create breathable air; they shield against particle showers and radiation from the sun; and there is a Faraday cage around the colony to protect from electrical disturbances like solar storms.

A Faraday cage is cool because it does not require energy itself. It is just a fine metal mesh that conducts electricity away. It was one of the first parts of the colony to be built.

**Late: Radiation-Denying Chapeau**

[image]

Solar flares shoot out lots of radiation. But most of this is absorbed by the atmosphere. Once you have created an atmosphere for the planet you are safe from solar flares.

Some of the leftover radiation can damage the power grid. But the effect is minor. [The biggest solar flare measured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_Halloween_solar_storms) caused a power outage in Sweden and some damage in South Africa.

[image]

Considering the size of the planet, most everywhere was safe from the solar storm. It is easier just to rebuild than to try to protect everything on the surface.

The flare creates a temporary increase in radiation and particle showers. Some of this penetrates the atmosphere. But you can ensure against that with a handy headpiece that you and your children can make at home from common household items.